# Changing boolean value 0 to -1 within a Laravel application while making an Ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

So, I have a table which stores likes and dislikes

```
Likes
--id
--post_id
--user_id
--like
```

The column *like* stores a value 1 or 0 to represent a like or dislike.
I would like to change the 0 to -1 whenever you dislike.
I followed a tutorial when I built the code below, I tried to change certain variables to replace the 0 with a -1, by making a if statement which check the value of `$request['isLike']` in the controller. I were able to make so the application stores a dislike as -1, but that screwed up the ajax functionality.
Couldn't figure out how to get this whole thing to work properly.

I just want to keep the same functionality but change the value which gets stored for a dislike to -1 instead of 0.

**View:**

```
 <a href="#" class="like">{{ Auth::user()->likes()->where('post_id', $post->id)->first() ? Auth::user()->likes()->where('post_id', $post->id)->first()->like == 1 ? 'You like this post' : 'Like' : 'Like' }}</a> |
 <a href="#" class="like">{{ Auth::user()->likes()->where('post_id', $post->id)->first() ? Auth::user()->likes()->where('post_id', $post->id)->first()->like == 0 ? 'You don\'t like this post' : 'Dislike' : 'Dislike' }}</a>

<script>
    var token = '{{ csrf_token() }}';
    var urlLike = '{{ route('like') }}';
</script>
```

**app.js:**

```
var postId = 0;

$('.like').on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    postId = event.target.parentNode.parentNode.dataset['postid'];
    var isLike = event.target.previousElementSibling == null; //Checks if it's a like or dislike.

    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: urlLike,
        data: {isLike: isLike, postId: postId, _token: token}
    })
    .done(function(){
        //Change the page when .ajax has been executed.
        event.target.innerText = isLike ? event.target.innerText == 'Like' ? 'You like this post' : 'Like' : event.target.innerText == 'Dislike' ? 'You don\'t like this post' : 'Dislike';

        //Make sure you can't dislike and like at the same time.
        if(isLike){
            event.target.nextElementSibling.innerText = 'Dislike';
        } else {
             event.target.previousElementSibling.innerText = 'Like';
        }
    });
});
```

**Controller:**

```
public function postLikePost(Request $request)
    {
        $post_id = $request['postId'];
        $is_like = $request['isLike'] === 'true'; //Get's passed as string in request, changed to boolean. 
        $update = false;

        $post = Post::find($post_id);
        if(!$post){
            return null;
        }
        $user = Auth::user();
        $like = $user->likes()->where('post_id', $post_id)->first(); //First has to be specified
        if($like){
            $already_like = $like->like;
            $update = true;

            //Deletes if it already exists.
            if($already_like == $is_like){
                $like->delete();
                return null;
            }
        } else {
            $like = new Like(); //Creates new row for Like in table
        }
        $like->like = $is_like; //Set's whatever $like->like to whatever $request['isLike'] passed.
        $like->user_id = $user->id;
        $like->post_id = $post_id; 

        if($update){
            $like->update();
        }else{
            $like->save();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now your controller is setting `$is_like` to either `true` or `false` based on the value of the request data.

Later on your are setting `$like->like = $is_like;` which will cause the `like` property of the `$like` object to either `true` or `false`.

when you save, and persist the object to the database, the `like` field will be stored as either `1` (`true`) or `0` (`false`).

To accomplish what you want you could try something like
`$like->like = $is_like ? 1 : -1`

This will cause your `false` value to be stored in the database as -1.

However, when you check that field in your code, you will have to check if it is equal to `1` or `-1` rather than `true` or `false`, because in PHP `-1 == true`